# To correspond Global HTTP Batch Endpoint changes of Google Client API for Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

As google mentioned in ["Discontinuing support for JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch Endpoints"](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html), Google API Client Libraries have been regenerated to no longer make requests to the global HTTP batch endpoint.
I am currently using the Google API Client Libraries for Java(v1.20.0) to create/modify/remove users and to grant/revoke roles to GSuite via Google Admin SDK and Batch.

I searched for the latest version on [Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/releases), but there was no new release after publishment of this article.
I'd like to know whether the latest version on Github (v1.23.0) includes the update in endpoint? (which means I can just simply update to v1.23.0 and use it instead of the current version I am using).

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, yes, the update to API specific URLs was in v1.23.0. Make sure to update your google-api-services-* library versions too.